# Can you call Firestore.instance multiple times in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Working with Flutter app and Cloud Firestore plugin.  Seems you can call Firestore.instance anytime you need to, but looking at the example app from the plugin documentations they set it up differently then the readme.  They initialize it in the main file and then reference the main one like this:

```
final FirebaseApp app = await FirebaseApp.configure(
    name: 'test',
    options: const FirebaseOptions(
      googleAppID: '1:79601577497:ios:5f2bcc6ba8cecddd',
      gcmSenderID: '79601577497',
      apiKey: 'AIzaSyArgmRGfB5kiQT6CunAOmKRVKEsxKmy6YI-G72PVU',
      projectID: 'flutter-firestore',
    ),
  );
  final Firestore firestore = Firestore(app: app);

  runApp(MaterialApp(
      title: 'Firestore Example', home: MyHomePage(firestore: firestore)));
}
```

Is this required?  I'm getting a weird error with streams where if I create a stream and send any kind of data that updates the stream, then exit the app and relaunch it.  The app crashes when I try to push data to that stream again.  Im working on a chat feature so my chat page streams all the messages like so:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    DMProfile dmProfile = Provider.of<DMProfile>(context);
    PlayerProfile playerProfile = Provider.of<PlayerProfile>(context);
    return StreamBuilder<List<Message>>(
      stream: Firestore.instance
          .collection('chats')
          .document(widget.chatId)
          .collection('messages')
          .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
          .limit(20)
          .snapshots()
          .map((list) =>
              list.documents.map((doc) => Message.fromFirestore(doc)).toList()),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return LoadingPage();
        }
        List<Message> messageStream = snapshot.data;
        if (messages.length == 0) {
          messages = messageStream;
          hasMore = !(messageStream.length < 20);
        } else if (messages.first.timestamp != null &&
            messageStream.first.timestamp != null) {
          if (messageStream.first.timestamp
                  .compareTo(messages.first.timestamp) !=
              0) {
            print('Not equal');
            messages.insert(0, messageStream.first);
          }
        }
        return Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
            reverse: true,
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 20.0),
            controller: listScrollController,
            itemCount: messages.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              final messageText = messages[index].message;
              final messageSender = messages[index].senderId;

              final currentUser =
                  widget.isPlayer ? playerProfile.userId : dmProfile.userId;

              return MessageBubble(
                imageUrl: messageSender == playerProfile.userId
                    ? playerProfile.imageUrl
                    : dmProfile.imageUrl,
                text: messageText,
                isMe: currentUser == messageSender,
              );
            },
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

I send messages like this:

```
sendMessage({
    String sender,
    String receiver,
    String message,
    bool isPlayer,
    String dmName,
    String playerName,
    String dmImage,
    String playerImage,
  }) async {
    String sender1 = sender.compareTo(receiver) < 0 ? sender : receiver;
    String sender2 = sender.compareTo(receiver) > 0 ? sender : receiver;
    String chatName = '${sender1}_$sender2';
    await Firestore.instance
        .collection(CHAT_COLLECTION)
        .document(chatName)
        .setData({
      'dm': isPlayer ? receiver : sender,
      'dm_image': dmImage,
      'dm_name': dmName,
      'player': isPlayer ? sender : receiver,
      'player_image': playerImage,
      'player_name': playerName,
      'dm_hidden': false,
      'player_hidden': false,
      'timestamp': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      'dm_seen': isPlayer ? false : true,
      'player_seen': isPlayer ? true : false,
      'last_message': {
        'message': message,
        'sender_name': isPlayer ? playerName : dmName,
        'sender_id': sender,
        'receiver_id': receiver,
      },
    }, merge: true);
    await Firestore.instance
        .collection(CHAT_COLLECTION)
        .document(chatName)
        .collection(MESSAGES_COLLECTION)
        .add({
      'sender_id': sender,
      'receiver_id': receiver,
      'sender_name': isPlayer ? playerName : dmName,
      'message': message,
      'timestamp': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    });
  }
```

But if I do these steps:

1. Launch App and go to chat screen (stream initiated)
2. Back out of the app with the back button on Android
3. Reopen app and go to chat screen (stream initiated again)
4. Send a message
   I get the following error and the app crashes:

   E/AndroidRuntime(21665): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   E/AndroidRuntime(21665): Process: com.crimsonowl.scryer, PID: 21665
   E/AndroidRuntime(21665): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.invokeMethod(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
   E/AndroidRuntime(21665):    at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.cloudfirestore.CloudFirestorePlugin$EventObserver.onEvent(CloudFirestorePlugin.java:451)
   E/AndroidRuntime(21665):    at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.cloudfirestore.CloudFirestorePlugin$EventObserver.onEvent(CloudFirestorePlugin.java:433)
   E/AndroidRuntime(21665):    at com.google.firebase.firestore.Query.lambda$addSnapshotListenerInternal$2(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.3.0:1025)
   E/AndroidRuntime(21665):    at com.google.firebase.firestore.Query$$Lambda$3.onEvent(Unknown Source:6)
   E/AndroidRuntime(21665):    at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.AsyncEventListener.lambda$onEvent$0(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.3.0:42)
   E/AndroidRuntime(21665):    at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.AsyncEventListener$$Lambda$1.run(Unknown Source:6)
   E/AndroidRuntime(21665):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
   E/AndroidRuntime(21665):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
   E/AndroidRuntime(21665):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.tasks.zzb.dispatchMessage(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.0.2:6)
   E/AndroidRuntime(21665):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
   E/AndroidRuntime(21665):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
   E/AndroidRuntime(21665):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   E/AndroidRuntime(21665):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
   E/AndroidRuntime(21665):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
   I/Process (21665): Sending signal. PID: 21665 SIG: 9

Ive tried everything and looked through as much documentation as I could and cant seem to find a solution.

Comment: This is a known issue and is being tracked [here](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/2517)

Answer (score 1):

After looking thru the github page for cloud_firestore and reading some of the other posted issues, this is a bug with the newer versions of cloud_firestore.  Downgraded to `0.13.4+2` for now and it fixes the issue.  Will need to keep an eye on future releases and bug fixes to see when this one gets resolved.  Flutter official packages have been having great support and frequent updates though

Answer (score 1):

To actually answer the title, yes, you can **use** `Firestore.instance` multiple times. It's not actually a function, so you don't actually '**call**' it. You're getting a static variable from a class.